# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay method not working properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, selector

I have an app with a small uiimageview circle that fades in and out into two different locations. When the user touches the screen I want the circle to fade out immediately, and i want it to stop fading in and out into moving locations. So basically touching the screen kills the circle.

After the circle is killed though I want another circle to spawn and do the same thing (fading in and out into 2 different locations) until the user touches the screen, then i want that circle killed, and another circle to spawn and etc...

here's my simplified code:

```
- (void)spawnCircle {
    self.circle = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.rectCircle];//alocate it and give it its first frame
    self.circle.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"];//make its image the circle image
    [self.view addSubView:self.circle];
    [self performSelector:@selector(fadeCircleOut)withObject:self afterDelay:2];//the circle will fade out after 2 seconds
    self.isFadeCircleOutNecessary=YES;
}

- (void)fadeCircleOut {

    if (self.isFadeCircleOutNecessary){//because after the circle fades in this method is scheduled to occur after 2 seconds, well, if the user has touched the screen within that time frame we obviously don't want this method to be called because we already are fading it out
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{//the circle will fade out for a duration of .5 seconds
            self.circle.alpha=0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished) {
                if (self.circle.frame.origin.x==self.rectCircle.origin.x) {//if its in the first location go to the second
                    self.circle.frame=self.rectCircle2;

                }else{//if its in the second location go to the first
                    self.circle.frame=self.rectCircle;
                }
                [self fadeCircleIn];//now were going to immediately fade it in its new location
            }
        }];
    }
}

- (void)fadeCircleIn {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{//fade it in with a duration of .5 seconds
        self.circle.alpha=1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(fadeCircleOut) withObject:self afterDelay:2];//after 2 seconds the object will fade out again
        }
    }];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^(){ self.circle.alpha=0;} completion:^(BOOL completion){//begin from current state makes it stop any animations it is currently in the middle of

        [self spawnCircle];//now another circle will pop up
        self.isFadeCircleOutNecessary=NO;
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self spawnCircle];
}
```

so the first time the circle spawns this works great but when the next circle spawns (after the user touches the screen and kills the first circle) the fade out method doesn't happen exactly after 2 seconds, it varies when it happens but it usually almost instantly fades out. so the delay part of the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: Is this performed on the main thread?

Comment: @H2CO3 yes it is, also see i made edits i forgot to include my (isCircleFadeOutNecessary) thing

Comment: OK, after the new edit my answer is useless. What you want to do is fix your whole code design and this problem will go. Do that by making a single animation that makes the circle fade in and out instead of calling the two methods separately. Use `CoreAnimation` & `CABasicAnimation` if possible.

Comment: @MindiHansenMende, One problem with above code is that you are creating  self.circle again without removing it from previous superview in touches began method. When you are calling [self spawnCircle]; it is creating a new instance and hence old one is still visible in the view, which is leaked and cannot be removed now. The below answer from rdelmar should work fine for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out your code, and got the same kind of results you did. I'm not sure what goes on behind the scenes with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, but it seems like once you get one going, it may still perform its function, even though you've created another circle.

I changed the code slightly by getting rid of the afterDelay calls, but putting the 2 second delay in the fade out method instead. See if this does what you want:

```
-(void)spawnCircle{
    self.circle=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.rectCircle];//alocate it and give it its first frame
    self.circle.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"];//make its image the circle image
    [self.view addSubview:self.circle];
    [self fadeCircleOut];
}

- (void)fadeCircleOut {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{//the circle will fade out for a duration of .5 seconds
        self.circle.alpha=0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            if (self.circle.frame.origin.x==self.rectCircle.origin.x) {//if its in the first location go to the second
                self.circle.frame=self.rectCircle2;

            }else{//if its in the second location go to the first
                self.circle.frame=self.rectCircle;
            }
            [self fadeCircleIn];//now were going to immediately fade it in its new location
        }
    }];
}

- (void)fadeCircleIn {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{//fade it in with a duration of .5 seconds
        self.circle.alpha=1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self fadeCircleOut];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        self.circle.alpha=0;
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL completion){//begin from current state makes it stop any animations it is currently in the middle of
                         [self.circle removeFromSuperview];
                         self.circle = nil;
                         [self spawnCircle];
    }];
}
```